# methylSigCalc function error

Tags: r

Trying to use the latest version of `methylSig` package (0.3.2), and getting an error when using the `methylSigCalc` function.
I get a cryptic error message after it figures out the number of loci:

> Total number of bases: 2.59m
>
> Error in result[, 3] : subscript out of bounds”

I tried running the code of the `methylSigCalc` function line by line, and the first error I encounter is when it gets to the `methylSig_dataProcess` function (below is the error after specifying just one core to try to get a useful error message):

> Error in do.call(rbind, lapply(which(validLoci),
>   methylSig_dataProcess,  :   error in evaluating the argument 'args' in
>   selecting a method for function 'do.call': Error in match.fun(FUN) :
>   object 'methylSig_dataProcess' not found

It does seem that `methylSig_dataProcess` is now missing from the package.
Any suggestions on where I might be going wrong?

Many thanks,
gogatea

Comment: Works fine for me in RStudio on Mac. I installed methylSig via `library(devtools); install_github('sartorlab/methylSig')`. I then have methylSig 0.3.2. The example given in the documentation `library(methylSig);data(sampleData);myDiffSig = methylSigCalc(meth)` runs without errors.

Comment: Did you also install this way? Does that example also fail on your computer?

Comment: I’m using a parameter file to specify how I want to run methylSig, so that it’s easy to run it in different configurations, and for the weightFunc I’m just specifying that it reads it as char, so when methylSig_dataProcess tries to actually use it, it doesn’t know it’s a function. So methylSig_processData breaks, because I made obj$weightFunc into a character variable.I fixed it by specifying it in the paramters text file as:
weightFunc      weightFunc <- function(u) { (1-u^2)^3 } function
Now using parse and eval to turn it into an actual function, it works.